# How to identify what type of SATA drive my laptop can take?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, macbook-pro

I have a 2011ish MacBook Pro. I want to upgrade its hard drive, but I am having trouble identifying:

1. What would be compatible my laptop.  For instance, [this SSD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148821&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=361116&SID=FWcrhryu) is SATA III.  How do I find out if my laptop even supports SATA III.
2. What would maximize my money.  Same example, let's assume my laptop does not support SATA III, but only SATA I.  Would it make sense for me to buy a SATA III SSD if my laptop can't take advantage of it?

Answer (score 0):

Your Macbook would at least support SATA II speeds, and would still provide you with a speed boost over a traditional mechanical drive in terms of loading times. Also, SATA II ports are compatible with SATA III drives so there shouldn't be any hardware compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the description on Apple site, but according [macforum](http://blog.macsales.com/10433-macbook-pro-2011-models-and-sata-3-0-6-0gbs-update-5272011) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) it goes with SATA 3, so go for this. However if you already have SATA 2 drive - it will work too.

Here is a simple table which shows how the mixing of SATA II and SATA III devices at the same bus results:

SATA 2 + SATA 3 = SATA 2

SATA 3 + SATA 2 = SATA 2

SATA 3 + SATA 3 = SATA 3

So does it have a sense to install SATA 3 SSD on SATA 2 notebook? It depends on circumstances. It hardly has a sense from the performance perspective as it will be narrowed down to the slowest SATA2. So if you are considering about buying more expensive SATAIII drive instead of cheaper SATAII you better know that it hardly brings speed benefits. At the same time the price difference is little relatively and if the money doesn't matter so why not to take SATAIII? If the notebook dies or you just have a chance to put it into a device with SATAIII then you will get more advantages with the more modern and, in fact, faster SSD.